# Can Sony smartwatch 2 be a NFC card

Tags: android, nfc, sony-smartwatch

I know that Sony smartwatch 2 has some limitations. It cannot read NFC tag, cannot transfer data rather than just for pairing with mobile phone.

I guess in this case, Sony smartwatch 2 is designed to be as a NFC Card, so that other phones can recognize and read data from this device. So if this assumption is true, can I write data to sony smartwatch 2 as a NFC card , because I think there still some empty space for data to be written into ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NFC functionality on SW2 is really only designed to be used to allow easy pairing to a phone.  There are no APIs to read/write using the NFC functionality on the watch unfortunately.